# Loco translate is only working on customizer but not translated on frontend

Tags: wordpress

I have translated a string by my theme but the translated text is display when I go to the customizer but it does not show on frontend.

Please check the screenshot -

- on customizer - http://prntscr.com/kyx09j
- on frontend - http://prntscr.com/kyx0o3
- loco translate - http://prntscr.com/kyx0xm

Comment: are you sure, that your theme is working with translations?

Comment: yes, it is working on WPML plugin.